# On a 'proof' of Polynomial Roots Mod p Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, proof-explanation

From the book A Friendly Introduction to Number Theory by J.H.Silverman :

[image]

and the proof goes on ...

My problem is that I can't understand the partial sentence "Now among all such polynomials" in the proof. How we form *the* set of all "such polynomials" so that we select one with least degree?

PS If we can form that set the minimum degree exists but if we can!

Comment: Can you explain exactly what difficulty you see in forming the set in question?  (Also, why do you think it is necessary to define that set in order to select one with least degree?)

Comment: @EricWofsey, The problem is that when I want to select one element from a set I think that first I do need to know that set (?)

Comment: They took the collection of all polynomials with more solutions than its degree. Then they assumed that there is at least one polynomial in that set. They plan to get a contradiction and disprove that assumption. Now, under that assumption you can derive that there is some polynomial in that set with minimum degree. In fact, the set of their degrees is a subset of the natural numbers. It is non-empty because the set of polynomials is being assumed non-empty. Therefore the set of degrees has a minimum and you can pick one polynomial that gave that degree.

Comment: Is your question about what the term "such polynomials" is referring to?  Or how you know that these polynomials form a set?  Or something else?